# Scalatra responseStatus

Tags: scala, scalatra

I'm new in scalatra, so how does `responseStatus(...)` works?
I mean, if I have a request

```
get("/..."){
    ...
}
```

and into this `get` I'll have:

```
...
100 -> "Continue",
...
```

What will be with this "continue" status? If question is incorrect, please correct me.

Comment: Are you saying you want to achieve http code as `100`? or asking why you are getting http code as `100`?

Comment: my case is to know, what will be if I achieve http code 100
(but you may be know another one,
 imagine situation, that I have get request, am I possible to send response to this request using just scalatra?)

Comment: you `Expect:` http code 100 when you want to wait and `post`/ `put` larger request body. here's info about that - https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html. Here's example how to use it with curl - https://gms.tf/when-curl-sends-100-continue.html. You can `response.setStatus(100)` to set http code.